# bundle install command does not show anything

Tags: ruby

I am pretty new to ruby. My server setup is required some ruby applications. I tried to install gitlab and one of the commands is:

```
sudo -u git -H bundle install --deployment --without development test postgres aws
```

it shows nothing, no error or success message and the command returns immediately.

I suspect that there is something not right there.

Some more useful info:

```
ruby --version
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-linux]

bundle --version
Bundler version 1.5.0
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Try running just `bundle install`

Comment: Also try putting the flags after the command `sudo bundle install -u git -H ...`

Comment: If I run bundle install without "sudo -u git", there is permission error because that is "git" home folder. Moving "bundle install" to the front still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

Because I upgraded new ruby version, it is not compatible with old bundle version. What I have to do is running:

```
sudo gem install bundler
```

to install compatible bundle version with new ruby.

It is solved.